# Shift 0-5V logic to ±2.5V logic

Tags: level-shifting

What's the simplest way at low speeds (sub 100 Hz) to shift 0-5V to ±2.5V? I was thinking of using a comparator or op-amp, but there must be a simpler / cheaper way. I wanted to avoid a dedicated chip, unless it is cheaper than a discrete solution. Any ideas?

Comment: What power supplies do you have available?

Comment: @markrages, 2.5V, -2.5V, 5V, -5V, GND and 1.8V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have -2.5V available, replace the two resistors with a single resistor to -2.5V.

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, the TL431 drops 2.495V, right? Could I use a 2.4V or 2.7V zener if accuracy wasn't critical?

Comment: Since this is low-speed logic, you can probably get away with a two-resistor voltage divider, with the low side at -2.5v. Calculate the hih and low levels, but it should work for standard CMOS I/O at least. If the 0-5v sigal is coming from a micrcontroller, the divider will draw some current through the protection diodes when the micro is in reset and all it's pins are inputs.  Use high-value resistors in the divider so this current isn't a problem.